# How to pass value for wherein in procedure of mysql

Tags: mysql

```
DELIMITER //

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS salary_ref//# MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows).
# MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows).

CREATE PROCEDURE salary_ref(con int(11),IN id varchar(120),maxval int(11),minval int(11) , taxo int(11))
BEGIN
DECLARE s VARCHAR(50);
IF con = 1 THEN
SELECT `i` . * , `taxo`.`id` , `t`.`item_id` AS id, `u`.`name` AS user_name, `t`.`value` AS val
FROM (
`taxonomy` AS taxo
)
JOIN `item_taxo` AS t ON `t`.`taxo_id` = `taxo`.`id`
INNER JOIN `items` AS i ON `i`.`id` = `t`.`item_id`
INNER JOIN `users` AS u ON `u`.`id` = `i`.`created_by`
WHERE `t`.`value`
BETWEEN minval
AND maxval
AND `t`.`taxo_id` = taxo
AND `i`.`parent_tag_id` in (id);
ELSE
SELECT `i` . * , `taxo`.`id` , `t`.`item_id` AS id, `u`.`name` AS user_name, `t`.`value` AS val
FROM (
`taxonomy` AS taxo
)
JOIN `item_taxo` AS t ON `t`.`taxo_id` = `taxo`.`id`
INNER JOIN `items` AS i ON `i`.`id` = `t`.`item_id`
INNER JOIN `users` AS u ON `u`.`id` = `i`.`created_by`
WHERE `t`.`value`
BETWEEN minval
AND maxval
AND `t`.`taxo_id` = taxo
AND `i`.`parent_tag_id` in (id);
END IF;
END;
//# MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows).

DELIMITER ;
```

//calling of that

call salary_ref(2,"\'36\',\'50\',\'57\'",17000000,0,7)

this is not work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following changes would solve the issues.

**Change 1**:
I suggest to not use same parameter names for stored procedure to represent column names of tables.
Unless you handle them properly there would arise an identifier conflict but does not seem to be there.

Change procedure signature as follows:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE salary_ref(
  _con int(11), IN csv_id_values varchar(120), 
  _maxval int(11), _minval int(11), _taxo int(11)
)
```

**Change 2**:
You are trying to pass comma separated values for `id` field to use in `where` clause.
But using escape character won't solve your problem and that is not correct way of using input values.

```
call salary_ref( 2, '36,50,57', 17000000, 0, 7 )
```

The CSV value `'36,50,57'` can be used as is for `where` clause.
See the suggested *Change* below.

**Change 3**:
You can use `FIND_IN_SET` on CSV values instead of `IN` in the `WHERE` clause.

```
 WHERE `t`.`value` BETWEEN _minval AND _maxval
   AND `t`.`taxo_id` = _taxo
   AND FIND_iN_SET( `i`.`parent_tag_id`, csv_id_values );
```

---

And, I think your procedure body is incomplete. Your `IF con` and `ELSE` are using the same `SELECT` statement. It is redundant, unless you change it.